Discontinuous Curveloop
I am using Python within Dynamo, and I am trying to create a CurveLoop from a given list of lines. However, I am encountering an error that says:

ArgumentException: This curve will make the loop discontinuous

I need to iterate over the list of lines and check if the start point of each line is not equal to the end point of the previous line. If they are not equal, I need to reverse the line, but I am unsure how to do that.
Here my script:
import clr
import sys
import System
import math

#import Revit API
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
import Autodesk.Revit.DB as DB
#import specify namespace



#import net library
from System import Array
from System.Collections.Generic import List, IList, Dictionary

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryReferences)

#import transactionManager and DocumentManager (RevitServices is specific to Dynamo)
clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

Lines = []
line1 = Line.CreateBound(XYZ(5,0,5), XYZ(5,0,0))
Lines.append(line1)
line2 = Line.CreateBound(XYZ(-5,0,0), XYZ(5,0,0))
Lines.append(line2)
line3 = Line.CreateBound(XYZ(-5,0,0), XYZ(-5,0,5))
Lines.append(line3)

curves = CurveLoop()

# how to append lines in the CurveLoop with the correct orientation and order?
for i in Lines:
    curves.Append(i)


OUT = curves

